# aws s3 downloading files

Tags: python, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2

I am trying to download a file from one of my Amazon s3 bucket to Ubuntu EC2 instance.I have two buckets created in 2 different regions, i can access and download files from the bucket of one region but when i try to access the other am facing a problem.

```
Here is the error,
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "listbucket.py", line 7, in <module>
    bucket = conn.get_bucket('train-faces')
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/boto/s3/connection.py", line 509, in get_bucket
    return self.head_bucket(bucket_name, headers=headers)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/boto/s3/connection.py", line 556, in head_bucket
    response.status, response.reason, body)
boto.exception.S3ResponseError: S3ResponseError: 400 Bad Request
```

But i can download file from the bucket of another region.

Comment: when you set up your AWS credentials you should have set up the default region. this may be why its working for one, not the other. are you specifying the region in your command? eg. --region us-east-1

Comment: no iam not specifying any region in the command but i have configured the region.

Comment: but if i change any other region in configuration its not working

Comment: try specifying it in the command

Comment: actually am using python code for downloading and i am specifying the access keys but not region to it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can specify the region when connecting with Amazon S3.

**boto**

```
import boto
conn = boto.s3.connect_to_region('ap-southeast-2')
conn.get_bucket('train-faces')
```

**boto3**

These days, it is recommended that you use [boto3](https://boto3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/):

```
import boto3
s3 = boto3.resource('s3', region_name = 'ap-southeast-2')
bucket = s3.Bucket('train-faces')
```

or

```
import boto3
client = boto3.client('s3', region_name = 'ap-southeast-2')
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use following commands to download

```
import boto3
s3 = boto3.client('s3','region_name')
s3.download_file("bucket-name", "key-name", "tmp.txt")
```

Please see http://boto3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/guide/s3.html

Explanation - We are first making a connect to s3 of particular Region. The reason that you are getting the file from one Bucket may be the value which you have set while configuring the boto. It is good practice to provide the region_name while making the connection.
Another Reason may be the file not accessible or permission denied. If later is the issue, then you should be the same error saying Permission Denied